# providing html contents directly to the servlet

Tags: java, html, gwt

we are providing html contents directly to the servlet,instead of that html file,but its not geting hit on onmoduleload() in the gwt entrypoint.
following is the snippet of my code,

```
String xml=getHtmlForAuthPage();
resp.getOutputStream().write(xml.getBytes());

public String getHtmlForAuthPage(){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(
                  "<html> "+
                  "<head>" +
                  "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\">" +
                  " <title>" +
                  "Auth test"+
                 " </title>"+
                      "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"auth.css\">"+
                   "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"com.ensarm.auth.auth/com.ensarm.auth.auth.nocache.js\">"+
                   "</script>"+
                   "<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\">" +
                 "</head>"+
                 "<body>"+
                 "<iframe src=\"javascript:''\" id=\"__gwt_historyFrame\" tabIndex='-1' style=\"position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0\">"+
                   "</iframe>"+ 
                  "<table align=\"center\" >"+
                    "<tr align=\"center\" valign=\"top\">"+
                    "<td align=\"center\" id=\"auth\">"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "</tr>"+
                    "<tr align=\"center\" valign=\"bottom\">"+
                    "<td align=\"center\" id=\"footer\">"+
                    "</td>" +
                   " </tr>" +

                " </body>"+
               "</html>");

        return sb.toString();

    }
```

Comment: Why do you use a `StringBuilder` if the string concatenation is still done using the `+` operator? It defeats the purpose.

Comment: Can you post the entire class and not just a section? Does the class that this code comes from implement EntryPoint (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/core/client/EntryPoint.html)? If so, is this class registered in your GWT configuration (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/create.html#components)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `resp.getWriter().print("your-html-content-here");`

This method is from [`ServletResponse`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29), and inherited by `HttpServletResponse`.

[`getOutputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29) is used for writing binary data.